# Can i include another php script to continue the for loop execution to prevent server timeout due max_execution_time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script which inserts data into database table with a function call, and the function is in the for loop. I want 120+ iterations, but due max_execution_time=30 and unfortunately i cant change or edit php.ini file on my shared hosting. 
As the execution of the script stops at approx. 55-60 iterations of for loop.
I was thinking that what if i include another php file like,
    include("script2.php");
can i continue the for loop from 61 and end at 120 in this script. So that i can complete all 120 iterations. 
Please correct me if i am wrong, i am new to php.

```
if (isset($_POST["roll"])&&isset($_POST["resultType"])){
    global $result;
    global $t;
    $result=new Parser($_POST["resultType"]);
    $n = $_POST["roll"];
    $t = substr($n, 0, strlen($n) - 3);
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rolltu");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    // Create table
    $sql="CREATE TABLE $t(NAME CHAR(30),ROLL CHAR(30) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(roll),Marks INT)";
    // Execute query
    if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        echo "Table $t created successfully. <br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con);
        echo "<br>";
    }
    $arr = array($t,'000');
    $s = join("",$arr);
    $q ="$s";
    $c = 120;
    for($i = 0;$i <$c;$i++) {
    $q++;
    $result->requestResult($q);
    showResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your script:

```
set_time_limit($time);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

> The maximum execution time, in seconds. If set to zero, no time limit is imposed.

Comment: its showing warning message as set_time_limit(); is disabled for security purposes..

Comment: Which means the shared hosting has safe_mode (http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) enabled. Then there is no workaround to increase the max execution time.

Comment: We need more information about your script. Are you getting any errors? We have no information about your Parser class. Try setting     `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', true);`

Answer (score 0):

Change the max execution time from within the script maybe:

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", $timeInSeconds);
```

Comment: I have set $timeInSeconds to 120 but the script terminates within 90 seconds

Comment: Try `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0)` and then, if you are allowed to change this setting, the script will never timeout and will run to completion.